# Is Google Guice active?

Tags: java, guice

There were no releases for over a year, not even minor bugfixes. Commits to the repository are infrequent and there have been no commits for last two months. Is it safe to start new project using this library?

Comment: Mature software doesn't need frequent updates.

Comment: @Esko - Agreed,  some problems are solved.  Guice is awesome,  I would suggest it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [pretty fresh answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-guice/T8LCD6GBU0I%5B1-25%5D) in their Google Group.

And [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/list?q=label:3.1) are current issues tagged as 3.1 candidates.

Answer (score 9):

Guice 4 is now in beta (see https://github.com/google/guice)

Comment: Guice 4 was released about 2 hours ago.

Answer (score 5):

Good news everyone!

Guice 4.0 released (https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice40)

Answer (score 4):

Guice is a largely feature-complete system.  There are bugs, there are improvements that are in process, but the core is stable and has been for quite some time.  That said, we've released 4.0-beta, so the new functionality, new constraints, new SPI additions are available for testing in the field.  We should be releasing 4.0 final this quarter, or early next quarter depending on whether some internal things get in quickly or not.

Comment: Is it possible to submit a patch for something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/21217883/693752