# Is it possible to limit type hierarchy scanning with Guice?

Tags: java, performance, dependency-injection, guice

Is there any way, when using Google's Guice injector to limit inheritance depth when scanning a class to find its dependencies ?

I mean, if you define a class A like

```
class A extends X {
 @Inject
 private B a;
}
```

And I got class inheritance : A --> X --> Y --> Z

I just want A to be scanned, and X, but not upper classes like Y and Z. I am pretty certain no fields can be injected in neither classes.

My goal is to boost startup phase.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RoboGuice team is actively working in this area. For those who are interested, RG 3.0 will include a fork of guice based on this technique.

More details here : https://speakerdeck.com/stephanenicolas/blender-boosting-guice-with-annotation-processing

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible and I'd bet the gain would be negligible. Guice only need to scan the class hierarchy once in order to collect the injection points and the usually more time-consuming part is the injection itself.

The cost of the injection itself is independent of the class hierarchy, it rather depends on the number of objects to be processed and number of fields to be injected.

Comment: thx for the answer. But my question applies more to Android where resources are really always quite limited. Both mounting up the reflection model of all classes and scanning them will consume resources for nothing, and I would like to limit this to only usefull information. Do you think such a feature could interest the Guice team (i.e. limiting scanning area) ?

Comment: @Snicolas: I'm pretty sceptical, I guess Guice is rather considered to be completed. You could patch it for yourself, but first do some good profiling so you don't waste your time.

Comment: Isn't Guice 4 in Beta @maartinus ?

Comment: I guess I was wrong... still, I can't see much happening there. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12039181/581205) could be considered authoritative if it was true.